# Get actual enum class of the Parameterized class T extends Enum<?>

Tags: java, generics, reflection, enums, parameterized-class

I have a class:

```
public class MultipleSorting<T extends Enum<?>> {
    private T criteriaType;

    public Class<T> getCriteriaClass() {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.getField(getClass(),"criteriaType");
        ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);
        return (Class<T>)field.getType();           
    }
}
```

This class is get instantiated as:

```
public abstract class MultiSortPageableController<T extends MultiSortPageableController<?,?>, U extends Enum<?>> {
    private MultipleSorting<U> multipleSorting;

    public MultiSortPageableController() {
        super();

        multipleSorting = new MultipleSorting<U>();
    }
}
```

The actual value of `U` is passed from the child class of `MultiSortPageableController` which is:

```
public abstract class AbstractArticleSearchController<T extends AbstractArticleSearchController<T>> extends MultiSortPageableController<T,ArticleSortField> {

}
```

The `ArticleSortField` is an `Enum`.

I was expecting the method `getCriteriaClass` of `MultipleSorting` would return `ArticleSortField` from a method of `MultiSortPageableController`. But it is returning `java.lang.Enum`.

I am unable to figure it out why it is not returning the actual enum and how can I make it so. Any pointer would be very helpful to me. I need to get `ArticleSortField`.

### Purpose:

I two requirement:

1. To get the actual class of enum type (say `ArticleSortField.class`)
2. To list enum value. If I have the enum class, then I could invoke `class..getEnumConstants()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java compiler removes information about generics, therefore when you use reflection you get no information about the declared type, other than Enum. This process is called [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html).

How about passing the type down, via the constructor, like this:

```
public class MultipleSorting<T extends Enum<?>> {
    private Class<T> criteriaType;

    MultipleSorting(Class<T> criteriaType) {
        this.criteriaType = criteriaType;
    }

    public Class<T> getCriteriaClass() {
        return criteriaType;
    }
}

public abstract class MultiSortPageableController<T extends MultiSortPageableController<?, ?>, U extends Enum<?>> {
    private MultipleSorting<U> multipleSorting;

    public MultiSortPageableController(Class<U> criteriaType) {
        super();

        multipleSorting = new MultipleSorting<U>(criteriaType);
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractArticleSearchController<T extends AbstractArticleSearchController<T>> extends MultiSortPageableController<T, ArticleSortField> {
    public AbstractArticleSearchController() {
        super(ArticleSortField.class);
    }
}
```

Comment: The field is null. I put it just to determine the class type at runtime. Because of the type erasure.